How to recognize change of variables $x=u\sec v$ and $y=u\tan v$ in $\iint_Re^{x^2-y^2}dA$, where $R$ is enclosed by $x^2-y^2=1, x^2-y^2=16, x=2y$?
Here is a problem from my book:

Evaluate $\iint_Re^{x^2-y^2}dA$, where $R$ is a region in the first quadrant, enclosed by the curves $x^2-y^2=1$, $x^2-y^2=16$, and $x=2y$. (Hint: use the following change of variables $x=u\sec v$ and $y=u\tan v$).

I'm confused by this hint. I wonder how anyone would recognize this change of variables in the first place (assuming the problem hadn't mention it).

Here is the change of the variables that I used for this problem:
Let $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=\dfrac yx$, we have $u\in[1,16]$ and $v\in[0,1/2]$.
$$
J'=\begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\  \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 2x & -2y \\  \dfrac{-y}{x^2} & \dfrac{1}{x} \end{vmatrix}=2-\dfrac{2y^2}{x^2}=2(1-v^2)$$
So $J=\dfrac1 {2(1-v^2)}$. The integral is
$$\iint_R e^{x^2-y^2}dA=\int_1^{16}\int_0^{1/2}\dfrac{e^u}{2(1-v^2)}dvdu=\int_1^{16}\dfrac14\ln\left|\dfrac{1+v}{1-v}\right|e^u\vert^{v=1/2}_{v=0} du$$
$$=\dfrac14\ln(3)e^u\vert^{16}_1=\dfrac14\ln(3)(e^{16}-e)$$

How is this different from your previous question?

@SineoftheTime In the previous question, I solved the problem using my own change of variables, but here I specifically asked for elaboration on the suggested trigonometric change of variable in the book's hint.

The hint is a twist on the typical conversion to polar coordinates. For either integral of $e^{x^2\pm y^2}$, the idea is to exploit the Pythagorean identities
$$\cos^2v+\sin^2v=1 \iff 1=\sec^2v-\tan^2v.$$
Alternatively, we can apply the hyperbolic analogue,
$$\cosh^2v-\sinh^2v=1$$
considering $R$ is bounded by a hyperbola on two sides.
$$(x,y)=(u\cosh v,u\sinh v)\implies \begin{cases}x^2-y^2=u^2 \\[1ex]\dfrac yx = \tanh v \\[1ex]\left\lvert\dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right\rvert =  \det \begin{bmatrix}\cosh v&u\sinh v \\ \sinh v&u\cosh v\end{bmatrix} = u\end{cases}$$
$$\implies\iint_R e^{x^2-y^2}\,dA = \int_{v=0}^{\operatorname{arcoth}2} \int_{u=1}^4 u e^{u^2} \, du \, dv$$
